# Cookies aren't set and being shown in browser using Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, cookies

I'm creating a login module but I have some problems with a checkbox to remember the user login info.

Using the below code to set a cookie:

```
String remember = String.valueOf(req.getParameter("remember"));
//*** set a cookie if user select remember me
if (remember.equals("on")) {
    System.out.println("remember me selected: " + remember); //*** ok
    Cookie emailCookie = new Cookie("email_key", req.getParameter("email"));
    emailCookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 7); //*** one week
    resp.addCookie(emailCookie);
    System.out.println("cookie :" + emailCookie.getValue() + " added"); //*** ok
}
```

But after that I expect to see the *email_key* and its value in the *browser's inspect element* but there is nothing in firefox.

Also if I use the below code to get cookies:

```
Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
for (Cookie c: cookies) {
     System.out.println(c.getName() + " " + c.getValue()); 
}
```

I will get just *JSESSIONID* as the name and some string which I don't know what is it as the value(the same name and value is shown in inspect elemet of browser).

It seems everything is ok. But where is the problem and how can I set cookies and use them?!

Comment: do you see the "Set-Cookie" header in your response?

Comment: @ianaz no. where can I see it?

Comment: you should be able to see it in the browser, when you get the response from your first request. A Set-Cookie header should be send too as it's telling the browser to save it :) Depending on the case, could be not shown (for ex in Secure mode) but I don't think you're that far since you're trying locally and with basic cookie